# Iterating over a series of objects and inserting then into a Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

All in all trying to loop over a jsonplaceholder's (/users) name, username, and email. Im getting the data with the help of axios and im displaying it through react. I have two seperate files: App.js (the one that comes with react) and AlbumList.js

In App.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import './App.css';

    import AlbumList from './Components/AlbumList';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <AlbumList/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default App
```

And in Album.List

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';

export default class AlbumList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        persons: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({ persons: res.data });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <caption>List of users</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">name</th>
                        <th scope="col">username</th>
                        <th scope="col">e-mail</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            {/* { this.state.persons.map(person => <div>{person.name} | {person.username} | {person.email}</div> )} */}
            </div>

            )
    }

}
```

The table im using is the one that bootstrap offers, the default one. How do I do this? thanks

Comment: Try to use about map function!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the data you got from your fetch request to the "tbody" tag, here you are just mapping the result in a div.

Check below your code with the modification needed:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <caption>List of users</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">name</th>
                        <th scope="col">username</th>
                        <th scope="col">e-mail</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
{ this.state.persons.map(person =>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row"></th>
                        <td>{person.name}</td>
                        <td>{person.username}</td>
                        <td>{person.email}</td>
                        </tr> )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

            )
    }
```

Edit: typo